# hbase-indexer solr numFound different from hbase table rows size

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase, apache-phoenix

Recently my team is using hbase-indexer on CDH for indexing hbase table column to solr . When we deploy hbase-indexer server (which is called Key-Value Store Indexer) and begin testing. We found a situation that the rows size between hbase table and solr index is different :

We used Phoenix to count hbase table rows:

```
0: jdbc:phoenix:slave1,slave2,slave3:2181> SELECT /*+ NO_INDEX */  COUNT(1) FROM C_PICRECORD;

+------------------------------------------+
|                 COUNT(1)                 |
+------------------------------------------+
| 4084355                                  |
+------------------------------------------+
```

And we use Solr Web UI to count solr index size :

```
numFound : 4060479
```

We could not found any error log from hbase-indexer log and solr log. But the rows size between hbase table and solr index is really different !  Is there anyone meet this situation ? I don't know how to do

Comment: whats the unique id in solr...? is it different from hbase...?

Comment: the unique id in solr schema.xml is the same with hbase rowkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding :

Hbase rowcount - Solr rowcount(numfound) = missing records

4084355 -  4060479 = 23876 (which are there in Hbase and missing in Solr)

The Key-Value Store Indexer service uses the Lily HBase NRT Indexer to index the stream of records being added to HBase tables.

NRT works on incremental data not whole data.

**Out of my experience these are possible reasons :**

1) NRT worked initially, and if suddenly NRT is not working(due to some health issues) then there is a possibility of discrepancy in numbers.

2) NRT works on WAL(write ahead log) if WAL is switched off while inserting the records in to HBASE (possible.. for performance reasons), NRT wont work.

**Possible solution :** 
1) Delete Solr documents and freshly load data in to Solr from Hbase. 
 Hbase batch indexer you can run on whole data (Batch indexer wont work on incremental data, it works on whole dataset)

2) As part of data-flow pipe line, Write a map-reduce program to insert the data in to solr.(what we have done in one of our implementation)

Comment: maybe you are right. In your solution 1) , image this scene  : hbase data will increase daily and we need hbase-indxer to store index uninterruptedly.  if we run batch indexer to batch whole data,  during the mapreduce job , the increment data may come and this kind of data will be observed by hbase-indexer ? This may cause the solr index size diff with hbase table rows size again ? If true, It is very awful !

Comment: Hi, RamPrasad G, Recently we found the reason why the numfound of solr is different from hbase row count. It only occur when our hbase table have been created phoenix secondary indexes. If no index table follow the data table, after importing data finished, the numfound in solr is the same as hbase table row count. I found this situation using jconsole to watch hbase-indexer metrics [https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer/wiki/Metrics](https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer/wiki/Metrics) But we don't know why it will happen ...

Answer (score 0):

All right, we solved the problem recently.

The reason why solr numfound is different from hbase table row count due to hbase-indexer make a mistake
of deleting some row instead of inserting them. We found this situation according to hbase-indexer metrics :
https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer/wiki/Metrics

We use jconsole to watch jmx metrics data and found :

indexer deletes count = hbase table row count - solr numfound

Finally we debug into the hbase-indexer source code and find some code will cause this problem, maybe it is a issue about hbase-indexer, please see : https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer/issues/78